# Interactive Services Detection

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio, interactive

What is causing this ? What did I do wrong ? How do I stop the behavior ?

- Turned on machine.
- Loaded Apps to go to work
- Got this...

> INTERACTIVE SERVICES DETECTION,  A PROGRAM RUNNING ON THIS COMPUTER IS TRYING TO DISPLAY A MESSAGE

- He wouldn't go away.
- I looked up the message on Bing and Google.
- Found a page on Microsoft's site, and one on Norton Symantec (among others).

Skimming over the two pages on the two sites, I decided that this was not a virus, and I clicked.

Both screens went away at once and were replaced (both) with a flat, somewhat bright, very pale blue background.

There appeared to be a MessageBox on one of the screens, with these words...

> Microsoft Visual Studio
>
> The Application Data Folder for Visual Studio could not be created

So I clicked okay.

- The thing happened two or three more times.
- Finally it went away.
- Like, Duh.

Alms for the clueless ??? What is causing this ? It happens sometimes, but not always. Do I have a problem that will be really bad ? Or is this something that I'm just doing wrong in Visual Studio ?

For that matter, is this a system user thing, or some other kind of bug ? Or is it a bug in the first place ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: There, edited it. Are the questions surrounding this more clear now ? Hope I didn't overdo it.

Comment: Well, looks like Visual Studio doesn't have the permission to create folders. If I were you, I'd wipe it and re-install it. Because being a Microsoft product, it should know well how to ask Windows for the appropriate permissions. And uhm. Run an antivirus scan, just in case. With weird things like this.

Comment: It's Visual Studio 2010 on Win'7 if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening is there is a service attempting to interact with the user.  Services are now only allowed to do this in a limited way.  A Windows Update probably broke something for you.

The following might help:
In services (services.msc), find the service that is failing for you, Right-click and select Properties then on the Log On tab select "Allow service to interact with desktop".  Now you should have the option to "View the Message" in Interactive Services Detection to see what your program is attempting to tell you.

Your long-term fix will be to uninstall the old program and get a newer copy of the service that does not attempt to pop messages up on a user's screen.

A short-term fix would be to disable the "Interactive Services Detection" service: the popup would go away and whatever is causing it will silently fail, so not a very good fix.